# Type hinting class members with PHPStorm

Tags: php, oop, phpstorm, type-hinting

I am currently writing a plugin system. I have a main class instance called $core with a directory of autoloaded plugins. When they load they then become a property of $core, e.g. `$core->foo->fn()` and `$core->bar->fn()`.

The plugins have to sit in a separate folder and cannot alter the Core class. Basically, how do I add the type hint on Core without actually editing the class itself?

Comment: I do not think that it is possible to do this using PHP syntax (PHPDoc or whatever) with those limitations (PHPDoc for class should be placed just before the class itself, and since you cannot edit that class...). You should be able to do this by writing custom plugin for PhpStorm, that could add such info to already indexed (by IDE) class at runtime (maybe look at Symfony plugin that seems to do similar task).

Comment: `/** @var Core $core */` on the line above.